# Django: OperationalError at /admin/store/customer/ no such column

Tags: django, python-3.x

[Admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK3Wr.png)
[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO4jF.png)

I'm getting the following error when I make changes in the admin page: OperationalError at /admin/store/customer/ no such column: store_customer.email

In the admin page, there is a Customer column, where I can add or edit customer's information. I was able to access the admin page but whenever I click to the Customers page it gives me an error.

Please feel free to comment for any suggestions or advice. I'm still fairly new to Django workframe. Here are my codes below:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url


class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import *

admin.site.register(Customer)
admin.site.register(Product)
admin.site.register(Order)
admin.site.register(OrderItem)
admin.site.register(ShippingAddress)
```

migrations folder:

0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.7 on 2020-06-09 08:31

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Customer',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)),
                ('email', models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Order',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('date_ordered', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('complete', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('transaction_id', models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)),
                ('customer', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='store.Customer')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)),
                ('price', models.FloatField()),
                ('digital', models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False, null=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ShippingAddress',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('address', models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)),
                ('city', models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)),
                ('state', models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)),
                ('zipcode', models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)),
                ('date_added', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('customer', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='store.Customer')),
                ('order', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='store.Order')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='OrderItem',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('quantity', models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0, null=True)),
                ('date_added', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('order', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='store.Order')),
                ('product', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='store.Product')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

migration folder:

0002_auto_20200609_1209.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.7 on 2020-06-09 12:09

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('store', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='product',
            name='image',
            field=models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=''),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='product',
            name='digital',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

If you need more information about my code I will provide them for you.
Thank you

Comment: Have your migrations been run against the current DB?

Comment: I don't really quite understand your question but whenever I ran makemigratins and migrate I don't get any errors

Comment: zwhat output to you get when you run migrate? Cam you cheer the `ahow migartions frtsf

Comment: This is what I get when I ran migrate command: Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, store
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Answer (score 0):

python manage.py migrate --fake